# How to pass SqliteDatabase object to another activity in android?

Tags: android, sqlite

How to pass SqliteDatabase object from one activity to another activity in different framework?

Comment: You can't pass instance of an object from one activity to another..

Comment: For that you have to create a singleton on the application level and you can access database object from there.

Comment: why you need to pass database object ?, Create a model class and implements serrializable and pass it to intent.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass object through intent.putExtra and also you need to implement Serializable

```
SQLiteDatabase sqdb = ...;
intent.putExtra("sql_obj", sqdb);
```

To retrieve object

```
getIntent().getSerializableExtra("sql_obj");
```

Comment: implement serializable means, database class which extends SQLitedatabase should implement serializable?

Comment: implement Serializable to activity that you are calling from.

Comment: not applicable for the arguments (String, 
 SQLiteDatabase)

Comment: hey i have another way for you if you would like than create one another class that extends `SQLiteOpenHelper` that will be much easier for you. cause i always use this and never get stuck.

Answer (score -2):

Not the right way.
You dont need to pass `SQLiteDatabase` to another activity. You can create the instance of your `DatbaseHelper` class anywhere and call `getWritabelDatabase` to get the instance. All that you need is a context.

Also you can think of creating a singleton instance and can access the same instance from anywhere. Singleton instance makes your job much each as `SQLiteDatabase` are thread safe

Comment: let me know why -1 for this response?
I havn't seen anyone trying to pass SQLiteDatabase object from one activity to other, as it is absolutely not required.